# Algorithm Analysis: Big-O explanation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm currently taking a class in algorithms. The following is a question I got wrong from a quiz: Basically, we have to indicate the worst case running time in Big O notation:

```
int foo(int n) 
 {
    m = 0;
   while (n >=2)
   {
    n = n/4;
    m = m + 1;
   }   
   return m;
 }
```

I don't understand how the worst case time for this just isn't O(n). Would appreciate an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: because `n` is getting reduced by a factor of 4, it should be on a log scale

Comment: Hmm, interesting so in this case the worst case time would O (log n) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` calculates log4(n) by dividing `n` by 4 and counting number of 4's in `n` using `m` as a counter. At the end, `m` is going to be the number of 4's in `n`. So it is linear in the final value of `m`, which is equal to log base 4 of `n`. The algorithm is then `O(logn)`, which is also `O(n)`.

Comment: Calculates the ceiling of `log4(n)`, actually...  I think

Comment: curious, and still not clear to me, if n = 1000, it'll be run only handful of times, why would it be 0(n)?

Comment: @AD.Net Because [big-O is just an upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), not necessarily a tight upper bound. So it's also *O(n^2)*, *O(nlogn)*, *O(2^n)* and any other function you can think of that's larger than `log4(n)` for all `n` greater than some value.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that the worst case is O(n). That implies that the function takes at least n steps.

Now let's see the loop, n is being divided by 4 (or 2²) at each step. So, in the first iteration n is reduced to n/4, in the second, to n/8. It isn't being reduced linearly. It's being reduced by a power of two so, in the worst case, it's running time is O(log n).

Comment: "Let's suppose that the worst case is O(n). That implies that the function takes at least n steps." - No, that's not the definition of Big Oh. Big Oh is an upper bound, not a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

The computation can be expressed as a recurrence formula:

```
f(r) = 4*f(r+1)
```

The solution is

```
f(r) = k * 4 ^(1-r)
```

Where ^ means exponent. In our case we can say `f(0) = n`

So   f(r) = n * 4^(-r)

Solving for `r` on the end condition we have: `2 = n * 4^(-r)`

Using log in both sides, `log(2) = log(n) - r* log(4)`  we can see

```
r =  P * log(n);
```

Not having more branches or inner loops, and assuming division and addition are `O(1)` we can confidently say the algorithm, runs  `P * log(n)` steps therefore is a `O((log(n))`.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28r%2B1%29+%3D+f%28r%29%2F4%2C+f%280%29+%3D+n

Nitpickers corner: A `C` int usually means the largest value is `2^32 - 1` so in practice it means only max `15` iterations, which is of course O(1). But I think your teacher really means `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Okay, so now tell me if I've understood this correctly. Let's look at this hypothetical question: void foo (int n) { if ( n<=0) return; System.out.println(n); foo(n/3); } Would the worst case running time for be O(n), I'm trying to think of it in terms of the number of primitive operations –

Comment: @DavidWest Try running it with n=9 and see what you get.

Comment: @user3386109 when n = 9, our function basically prints out 9, 6 and 3. So in that case, doesn't it makes sense that our running is essentially a function of our input value, i.e O(n/3) which is basically O(n)?

Comment: @DavidWest You need to run the code you posted in your comment.

Comment: @DavidWest is not about number primitive operations, those are all O(1). It is about how many times it is looping as controlled by the input parameter.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry, it won't be 9,6,3. It will be 9, 3, 1

Comment: @AlienRancher so the looping is dependent on the input parameter so wouldn't our running time just be O(n) given that once we have a certain input we divide by 3 and then our functions runs until our input is zero.

Comment: @AlienRancher Actually, spending more time on this wouldn't this also just be O(log n) or maybeO (n log n) to be precise?

Comment: Lets use 256 and instead of dividing by 3 we divide by 2. So you get foo(256) { foo(128) { foo(64) { foo(32) { foo(16) { foo(8) { foo(4) { foo(2) { foo(1) }}}}}}}}}}  which is 8 (inner) times. This is exactly log2(256). So yes O(log(n)). O(n*log(n)) a whole different beast.